# MongoDB result set getting modified after execution of a query

Tags: java, mongodb, synchronization

In my application there are 2 threads:

1. crawl the web-sites and insert the data into MongoDB
2. retrieve the crawled sites and perform business logic

In order to retrieve the the crawled sites I use the following query:

```java
Document query = new Document("fetchStatus", new Document("$lte", fetchStatusParam));
FindIterable<Document> unfetchedEpisodes = dbC_Episodes.find(query);
```

As the result I get all episodes, which its `fetchStatusParam` is less or equal to the specific value.

The next step, I store the items of the result set in `HashMap<String, TrackedEpisode>`, which is an object property in order to track them:

```java
for (Document document : unfetchedEpisodes) {
    this.trackedEpisodes.put(document.get("_id").toString(), new TrackedEpisode(document));
}
```

Then I do some business logic, which:

- ***doesn't*** modify the `unfetchedEpisodes` result set.
- ***doesn't*** remove any object from `trackedEpisodes`.

Up till now everything is OK.
The last step, I pass over all retrieved documents and mark them as fetched in order to prevent the duplicate fetching in the future.

```java
for (Document document : unfetchedEpisodes) {

    if (this.trackedEpisodes.containsKey(document.get("_id").toString())) {

        // prevent repeated fetching
        document.put("fetchStatus", FetchStatus.IN_PROCESS.getID());

        if (this.trackedEpisodes.get(document.get("_id").toString()).isExpired()) {
            document.put("isExpired", true);
            document.put("fetchStatus", FetchStatus.FETCHED.getID());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("BOO! Strange new object detected");
    }

    dbC_Episodes.updateOne(new Document("_id", document.get("_id")), new Document("$set", document));
}
```

I run this code for a couple of days and paid attention that sometimes it arrives to the `else` part of the `if (this.trackedEpisodes.containsKey())` statement. It's weird for me, how it can be possible that `unfetchedEpisodes` and `trackedEpisodes` are not synchronized and don't contain the same items?

I began to investigate the case and paid attention that the times I arrive to `"BOO! Strange new object detected"` the `document` iterator contains the item which is in database but should not yet be in `unfetchedEpisodes` since I didn't execute a new query to database.

I checked couple of times the matter of storing retrieved items into `trackedEpisodes` and always all elements from the `unfetchedEpisodes` have been added to `trackedEpisodes` but after that sometimes I still arrive to `"BOO! Strange new object detected"`.

My question:

1. Why `unfetchedEpisodes` gets new items after execution of a query?
2. Is it possible that `unfetchedEpisodes` will be modified by MongoDB driver after execution of `Collection#query()`?
3. Maybe should I use kind of `.close()` after executing a query from the MongoDB?

The used versions:

- MongoDB: 3.2.3, x64
- MongoDB Java Driver: *mongodb-driver-3.2.2*, *mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2*, *bson-3.2.2*

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: From what I can see, I think your application architecture is a bit... ...improvable. Here is what I would do: have a producer (the crawler) sending the new sites down a pipeline, one of the steps being persisting the data, and applying business logic before (and after) as needed. Camel is very usable for this.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, it's hard to provide the minimal, complete and verifiable example without providing the whole crawler project.

Comment: Well, you have to put some effort into it ;) But take a deep look into my suggestion. Processing each site individually, potentially by many threads will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Yeap, actually, I'm working just with one site — a news aggregator, it accumulates all the data for me in one place, I just have to fetch it via RSS, store it in DB and after that process.

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/rss.html

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, I checked this framework, looks great but my project is a small academic project, thus we don't need to use a whole zoo of frameworks/APIs at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `find` here:

```
FindIterable<Document> unfetchedEpisodes = dbC_Episodes.find(query);
```

you are not actually getting all the episodes back. You are getting a database cursor pointing to the matched documents.

Then when you call:

```
for (Document document : unfetchedEpisodes){}
```

an iterator is created over all of the documents that match the query.

When you call it a second time, a new cursor is returned, for the same query, and all of the documents that match *now* are iterated over.

If the collection has changed in between, the results will be different.

If you want to ensure that the contents of `unfetchedEpisodes` are unchanged then one option is you could pull the entire result set into memory and iterate over it in memory rather than on the DB, e.g.

```
ArrayList<Document> unfetchedEpisodes = dbC_Episodes.find(query).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I do understand why it's changing. BTW, is it correct to assume that the database cursor works like a pointer and if I change the `document` within `for (Document document : unfetchedEpisodes){}` this change will be reflected in database without any additional operation (e.g. `updateOne()`)?

Comment: Nope when you access `document` within the loop, it has already been retrieved into memory and only the object in your application code will be updated, there is no synchronisation back to the database. You would have to perform an update operation.